# Push Notifications icon displaying gray color

Tags: c#, android, firebase, xamarin, xamarin.android

In my app Firebase push notification not displaying icon properly, It showing total gray color icon in notification.
Code I using for implementing notifications

```
var notificationBuilder = new Notification.Builder(this)
.SetSmallIcon(Resource.Drawable.ic_launcherLmg)
.SetContentTitle(user.Organization)
.SetSubText(user.ModuleName)
.SetContentText(user.BodyText)
.SetAutoCancel(true)
.SetContentIntent(pendingIntent)
.Build();
```

Icon I am setting at `SetSmallIcon(Resource.Drawable.ic_launcherLmg)` line.
ic_launcherLmg icon is available in below folders wtih given dimensoins

1. drawable-idpi--36x36
2. drawable-mdpi--48x48
3. drawable-hdpi--72x72
4. drawable-xhdpi--96x96

App targating Highest 8.1 API.
Minimun 5.0 API.

Screenshot of push notification

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally this issue solved by changing the color of icon. Whatever the content of  notification icon we want to show that should be in `Gray` color & background of icon should be `White`. Example image

[image]

I did not notice size concern, however the preferred size should be

- mdpi (160 dpi) 24 x 24 px
- hdpi (240 dpi) 36 x 36 px
- xhdpi (320 dpi) 48 x 48 px
- xxhdpi (400 dpi) 60 x 60 px

Comment: Then why are some icons not grey? The facebook Icon for example is blue

Answer (score 6):

Maybe your icon is not showing with background fcm push? So you need to put this inside application tag inside manifest as described here [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/data-cloud/google-messaging/remote-notifications-with-fcm?tabs=vswin#background-notifications):

```
<meta-data android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_icon"
    android:resource="@drawable/ic_launcherLmg" />
```

> Android displays this custom default icon for all notification messages where the notification icon is not explicitly set.

Comment: icon still not showing on my notifications. What else is necessary?

Answer (score 1):

You can use

**Use a mipmap icon instead of a drawable icon and put it in xxxhdpi-mipmap folder. The icon will automatically adjust its color if the background is white**

or

Use notification icon as android version like

```
.SetSmallIcon(getNotificationIcon())
```

and the function is or change it as you want

```
private int getNotificationIcon() {
    boolean useWhiteIcon = (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP);
    return useWhiteIcon ? R.drawable.icon_silhouette : R.drawable.ic_launcher;
}
```

Comment: this is a icon only, that is the reason i said change it as you want

Comment: in this case your icons is behave as well as android version

Comment: I tried your code but it didn't solve my problem. Thank you for answer.