# AppIcon in notification not filling all available space

Tags: xamarin.android, android-12

I'm generating a local notification using Xamarin.Android (Target Framework 12.1) like this:

```
NotificationCompat.Builder NoConnectionBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(Android.App.Application.Context, "CouldNotStartService");
            NoConnectionBuilder.SetSubText(Global_Warning)
                .SetContentText(Synch_InternetNotFound)
                .SetBadgeIconType((int)NotificationBadgeIconType.Large)
                .SetContentIntent(stopPi)
                .SetOngoing(true)
                .SetStyle(textStyle)
                .SetSmallIcon(Resource.Mipmap.ic_notification);
            if (Build.VERSION.SdkInt >= BuildVersionCodes.O)
            {
                NotificationChannel channel;
                channel = notificationManager.GetNotificationChannel(channelName);
                if (channel == null)
                {
                    channel = new NotificationChannel(channelName, channelName, NotificationImportance.Default)
                    {
                        LockscreenVisibility = NotificationVisibility.Public
                    };
                    notificationManager.CreateNotificationChannel(channel);
                }
                channel.Dispose();
                NoConnectionBuilder = NoConnectionBuilder.SetChannelId(channelName);
            }

            notificationManager.CancelAll();
            notificationManager.Notify(0104, NoConnectionBuilder.Build());
```

In my Resource.Mipmap folder I have **ic_notification.png** with different sizes:

```
mipmap-mdpi - 24x24
mipmap-hdpi - 36x36
mipmap-xhdpi - 48x48
mipmap-xxhdpi - 72x72
mipmap-xxxhdpi - 96x96
```

The generated notification looks like this (**the first one showing on the list**):
[image: Notification]

Seems my icon is not fulfilling all the given space. What can I do to show my icon the same way is showing the icon from the second notification on the list? (Testing it on samsung Android 13 real device)

Answer (score 0):

> AppIcon in notification not filling all available space

You can try to modify the size of ic_notification.png in Resource.Mipmap folder again. Like the case: [Push Notifications icon displaying gray color](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52224914/19902734).